# How to close the row of a table

Tags: tables

I've created a table and in the final row of the table, the end won't closer... any suggestions?

[image]

```
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|M{4cm}|M{4cm}|M{4cm}|}
\hline
\textbf{Causal Mechanism} & \textbf{Time Period (1979-1992)} & 
\textbf{Time Period (1992-2014)} \\
\hline
Oil Wealth & Low & High\\
\hline
Foreign aid-dependence & High & High\\
\hline
Challenges from domestic opposition & Low & High\\
\hline
Outcome & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Early} ratification of both IWRIs} \\

\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `\multicolumn` overwrites the formatting for every column covered by the number of columns. So, you'll have to use (re-)add the finishing vertical rule:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|M{4cm}|M{4cm}|M{4cm}|}
    \hline
    \textbf{Causal Mechanism} & \textbf{Time Period (1979-1992)} & 
      \textbf{Time Period (1992-2014)} \\
    \hline
    Oil Wealth & Low & High \\
    \hline
    Foreign aid-dependence & High & High \\
    \hline
    Challenges from domestic opposition & Low & High \\
    \hline
    Outcome & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\textbf{Early} ratification of both IWRIs} \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using `\multicolumn{2}{l}{....}` rewrite that as `\multicolumn{2}{l|}{...}`