# How to close up the table border in a multi-row situation?

Tags: tables

I've seen [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/453040/how-to-close-the-row-of-a-table), but it didn't work for me.

I'm having trouble closing up the right side border.

[image]

```
\begin {table}[H]
\caption{Oper} \label{table_oper}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Oper} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Max}\\
\hline
Swaps.\\
$C_{S}$\\
$\begin{aligned}
=\ {\sum_{j=1}^{m} {\sum_{j=1}^{m}}} {(C_{search}^{m}+C_{swap}^{m})}\\
*\ {{\sum_{j=1}^{m}}} {(C_{search}^{m}+C_{swap}^{m})}\\
*\ {{\sum_{j=1}^{m}}} {(C_{search}^{m}+C_{swap}^{m})}\\
\end{aligned}$\\ & -\\
\hline
Adj cost.\\
$C_{abc}$\\
$\begin{aligned}
=\ {\sum_{j=1}^{m} {C_{S}}} \\
\end{aligned}$\\ & -\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Tried `\multirow` for the first row like this:

```
\end{aligned}$\\ & 
\multirow{3}{*}{-}\\
```

but even that didn't work.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It would be helpful if you provided just a bit more information about your document setup. E.g., which document class do you employ? How wide is the text block?

Comment: Details: `\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}`. I haven't specified a text block width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you missed some `&` in your code and have two `\\` to delete after line `\end{aligned}$\\ & -\\`.

Please see the following MWE (I marked important code changings with `<=======`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin {table}
  \caption{Oper} 
  \label{table_oper}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Oper} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Max}\\
    \hline
    Swaps.   & \\ % <===================================================
    $C_{S}$  & \\ % <===================================================
$\begin{aligned}
=\ {\sum_{j=1}^{m} {\sum_{j=1}^{m}}} {(C_{search}^{m}+C_{swap}^{m})} \\
*\ {{\sum_{j=1}^{m}}} {(C_{search}^{m}+C_{swap}^{m})}\\
*\ {{\sum_{j=1}^{m}}} {(C_{search}^{m}+C_{swap}^{m})}\\
\end{aligned}$ & -\\ % <================================================
    \hline
    Adj cost. & \\ % <==================================================
    $C_{abc}$ & \\ % <==================================================
$\begin{aligned}
=\ {\sum_{j=1}^{m} {C_{S}}} \\
\end{aligned}$ & -\\ % <================================================
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image: resulting table]

I personaly would try to get rid of the vertical and horizontal lines but that is another question, I think ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You wrote,

> I'm having trouble closing up the left side border.

I will assume you meant the *right-hand side* border. The reason for the difficulty is that most of the `\\` directives occur too soon, i.e., without a `&` token first.

Your code contains lots of unnecessary pairs of curly braces, which achieve nothing but create code clutter. On the other hand, the equation could really do with a few more pairs of parentheses to delimit the scopes of the multiplication and summation operations. And don't use `*` to indicate multiplication; please use either `\times` or `\cdot`.

Moreover, the `aligned` environments don't contain any alignment points; I've apply some educated guesswork to backfill a few.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,float}
\newcommand\vn[1]{\mathrm{#1}}  

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Oper} 
\label{table_oper}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Oper} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Max}\\
\hline
Swaps.  & \\
$\begin{aligned}
C_{S} 
&= \sum_{j=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^m (C_{\vn{search}}^m+C_{\vn{swap}}^m)\\
&\quad\times    \sum_{j=1}^m (C_{\vn{search}}^m+C_{\vn{swap}}^m)\\
&\quad\times    \sum_{j=1}^m (C_{\vn{search}}^m+C_{\vn{swap}}^m)\\
\end{aligned}$ & --\\
\hline
Adj cost.&\\
$\begin{aligned}
C_{\vn{abc}}
&= \sum_{j=1}^m C_{S} \\
\end{aligned}$ & --\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your advice is gratefully accepted.